# Execute two stored procedures: what is the order they get executed?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I execute two stored procedures in the same connection like:

```
exec dbo.SP1;
exec dbo.SP2;
```

Can I be sure that `SP2` not will start before `SP1` is finished?

Comment: Yes - TSQL is sequential - no async here.

Comment: SQL is a sequential language, a statement further in the batch will not be started till those earlier in the batch complete.

Comment: @DaleK what if the first one fails. Yes thanks for the link

Comment: Define fail? If its a transaction breaking error it will not run SP 2, if its a minor error it will. If you care you should add error handling to control it.

Comment: *"what if the first one fails. Yes thanks for the link"* Depends on the severity of the error, your `XACT_ABORT` settings, etc.

Comment: @Larnu what if I want to start to SPs simultaneously on the same session? is that possible?

Comment: With 2 separate sessions, yes, @David .